# What did the taco say in "Sausage Party"

Tags: dialogue, translation, sausage-party

Okay so the hot Mexican lesbian taco girl said a couple of fast sentences in Spanish at one point maybe 1/2 to 3/4 of the way through the movie. I heard a bunch of Spanish-speaking people laughing, but I didn't get it. What is the Spanish to English translation?

Comment: Something something dick joke, probably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This clip?

The top comment gives a transcription:
"Tómala pinche, Douche de la chingada de mierda pendejo son of a bitch!"

Basic translation:
"Take that, Stupid Asshole Douche Fuck Son-of-a-Bitch!"